# Geokit issue - "could not find generator"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geokit

I am trying to get started with Geokit, and I ran the install command and was greeted with the following:

```
rails g geokit_rails:install
Could not find generator geokit_rails:install.
```

Any idea what's going on? I am so confused. bundle install works just fine. I run bundle exec rake db:migrate. but when I go into the console, when I try require 'geokit', I get false. I assume it's because the config file is missing? But how do I generate a sample config file to modify if the install script is failing??

Comment: What does your Gemfile look like?  Did you add `geokit` or `geokit-rails`?

Comment: I added geokit-rails to my Gemfile, bundle install worked perfectly fine. My Gemfile.lock include geokit-rails and geokit.

Comment: What version of geokit-rails?

Comment: version 2.1.0, which is the latest I believe

Comment: That's your problem.  The generator was only added 21 days ago.  It's not part of the 2.1.0 release.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that your version of the `geokit-rails` gem does not contain the generator.  It was added with https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails/commit/bb4261acef62a26de823c4b7306634ffb7c3381f.  The latest version of the gem is 2.1.0, and [as you can see here](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails/tree/v2.1.0/lib), the generators were not part of that release.

If you want to use the head version of the gem, then you can change your Gemfile to match `gem 'geokit-rails', github: 'geokit/geokit-rails'`.

Comment: sorry one last bit of help! this works perfectly, but how do I use Geokit through rails console? I tried require 'geokit', require 'geokit-rails', both returned false. everything else is setup. btw, I didn't change the config file at all (though it has been generated)

Comment: They're already included by the `Gemfile`.  You should be able to add the functionality to your models, i.e. `acts_as_mappable`... or do things like `Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode("Some location")`